# How to force webdriver to wait

Tags: python, html, selenium, wait

Im having this code, if there's the time.sleep(2) it clicks and if it's not there it doesnt click on the elements. It doesn't even wait a second

```
time.sleep(2)

WebDriverWait(self.broswer, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'something')))
self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('something').click()
```

I tried to use the following instead

```
self.browser.implicitly_wait(2)
```

but it doesnt wait and I cant use time.sleep()

Comment: It probably means that element is clickable right away. Is your locator correct?

Answer (score 0):

`Time.Sleep()` is counting time in milliseconds, therefore Time.Sleep(2) is 2 milliseconds, maybe if you try,

```
Time.Sleep(2000);
```

it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep()` and `WebDriverWait()` are different methods of waiting. It's best practice to avoid use of `time.sleep()` and prefer `WebDriverWait`.

In another comment you said that you don't even want to wait, you just want to click the button. If that's the case, you should be able to just use this

```
self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('something').click()
```

but you said that you get an error. What is the error that you get if you only run that one line?

Side note...
WebDriverWait.until() should return the WebElement specified so if you decide you want to keep the wait, you can do this

```
WebDriverWait(self.broswer, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'something'))).click()
```

I come from a Java background and don't know python so I may have some typos here and there... but this should get you headed in the right

Answer (score -1):

what is the problem with time.sleep()
If you don't want to user time.sleep() and still if you want to force web driver to wait for specific time then you can give condition also.

you can go through with below url for java

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Comment: I am not allowed to use the time sleep and Im not waiting for anything to do anything I just want to click the button and it doesnt wait it just throws an error and I dont understand why

Answer (score -1):

**1)**
Use the [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) (which is in **seconds** "Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds")only when you really need it.

**2)**
Learn, deeply, the differences between [IMPLICIT WAIT](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#implicit-waits) and [EXPLICIT WAIT](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Sometimes,I had the need to force the "physical" hard-ware wait, the I used the time.sleep(), but I really suggest you to comprehend the difference between the two waiting method which selenium provides you.

@Dor Alt: Remember that the (from documentation) "An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code." If you get any kind of error, please write it here and tell us which browser you're using for your test, because different browsers have (very, very and very) different behaviours! :)

I mean, if you are using Chrome and IE (as far as I know) if the webdriver doesn't have the visualization of the element you want to click, it does not click! In this case, for example, you should move/scroll the page with a script like this: driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, {0})'.format(element.location['y']))